# Ctrl + Space Not Working Properly Android Studio

Tags: android

i am facing problem in android studio. In eclipse when i want to use class like Intent, then i write intent starting with lower case it give me suggestion box indicating class name Intent, but in android studio if i type intent starting with lower case it does not Provide Suggestion class name Intent.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 29):

In my case Ctrl + Space was overloaded by mac shortcuts. And even in the case, I disabled them, they conflict with Android Studio.

So, I gave them another keys and it solved the problem.

Go to the `System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Input Sources` and use new keys for them.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, worked this way!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Android Studio has different key binding than Eclipse, but you can set the key binding to be the same as in eclipse in android studio settings. Also by default ctrl + space is case sensitive in Android studio, you need to turn that off too.

Move to File -> Settings -> Keymap and change keymaps settings to eclipse so that you can use the short cut keys like in eclipse.

You can set 'Case sensitive completion' to 'None' in IDE Settings > Editor > Code Completion.

That should do it :)

Comment: You need to turn off the case sensitive matching too

Comment: I'm glad you got it working, can you please accept this answer and close the question.

Answer (score 2):

`File --> Settings --> Editor --> General --> Code Completion --> Case sensitive completion --> None`